# SFML 'make install' SFML_OPENGL_ES missing include file

Tags: cmake, sfml

I was trying to install `SFML` on my mac (running Yosemite) using CMake GUI. The issue is when I try to do `sudo make install`.

Here is the output in terminal.

[image: Terminal Output]

`As you can see I get a fatal error: 'EGL/egl.h' file not found`

Here are the cmake options that I have enabled (using cmake GUI)

[image: cmake Options]

Also the source code directory is the root of [this](https://github.com/LaurentGomila/SFML) directory (i did `git clone`).

**Edit**
Found out that the issue is the SFML_OPENGL_ES option. How would I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you just want to install SFML to your Mac just uncheck the SFML_OPENGL_ES in cmake. OPENGL_ES is required if you want to build apps for iOS and Android, but not for Mac OS X.